# Deploying a spring boot micro service connected to mysql db to an external service on open shift through Jenkins pipeline

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins, microservices, openshift

I'm new to the deployment space (only ever did development) and I'm wondering if there are any tips or best practices to successfully accomplish this that anyone on this platform can provide. I'm successful at deploying this micro service on my localhost (db included) but have yet to gain success on an external service specifically open shift. I'm wondering if I need to containerize a bit differently, if so, not sure what images to containerize for this to be successful? I was just curious if there are tips/advice/best practices that anyone can provide that has experience with deploying micro services using mysql db to external service. Please let me know if there are any additional pieces of info I can provide here that I've left out.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For the application-side of things, I recommend following the [12 factors](https://12factor.net/). Of particular interest here is [III. Config](https://12factor.net/config). We can

- externalize the configuration of the database into environment variables, and then
- provide them through [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables)s, [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#use-case-as-container-environment-variables)s, or both (e.g. provide the DB url and port through a `ConfigMap`, provide username and password through a `Secret`).

If the database is hosted in OpenShift/k8s aswell, I recommend to define it as separate Deployment/StatefulSet.

To manage the deployment(s), there are additional tools, e.g.:

- [`kustomize`](https://kustomize.io/) to manage/build kubernetes manifests
- [ArgoCD](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as deployment solution to do the "heavy-lifting" and deploy the kubernetes manifests to the cluster.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you for the direction. I'm looking into your approach right now.